# Python multiprocess plot issue in Mac OSX Sierra - exception type EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, python-multiprocessing, macos-sierra, exc-bad-instruction

I've developed a GitHub repo with an example of a [multiprocess script in python2.7 for plotting](https://github.com/maximiliano1985/PythonMultiprocessingPlot). Basically, the script allocates one process to generate the data, and such data are passed via a queue to a second process that is responsible to generate the plot. When I run both the examples 'multiproc_processIPC.py' or 'multiproc_poolQUEUE.py' I get the following error.
Note that this error came up AFTER upgrading my mac to OSX Sierra.
Has anyone a clue of the origin of this issue?
Any help will be highly appreciated

===== ERROR REPORT =====

> Process:               python2.7 [82890]
>   Path:                  /Users/USER/*/python
>   Identifier:            python2.7
>   Version:               ???
>   Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
>   Parent Process:        python2.7 [82883]
>   Responsible:           python2.7 [82890]
>   User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2016-12-04 22:34:29.874 +0100
>   OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.1 (16B2555)
>   Report Version:        12
>   Anonymous UUID:        689587A6-D759-0F81-671D-1079942B7C42
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 9000 seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
>   Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
>   Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
>   Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
>   Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]
>
> Application Specific Information:
>   BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBDISPATCH: _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF called from the wrong thread
>   crashed on child side of fork pre-exec
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>   0   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff8f9ddd21 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1291
>   1   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff7a97abe9 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9
>   2   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff7a93c00d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
>   3   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff7a93b514 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
>   4   com.apple.HIToolbox               0x00007fff79ed8fbc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240
>   5   com.apple.HIToolbox               0x00007fff79ed8df1 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
>   6   com.apple.HIToolbox               0x00007fff79ed8c26 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
>   7   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff785c2b79 _DPSNextEvent + 1093
>   8   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff78cd81c3 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1637
>   9   Tk                                0x0000000104b01285 0x104a47000 + 762501
>   10  Tk                                0x0000000104b0171f 0x104a47000 + 763679
>   11  Tcl                               0x00000001049d75f8 Tcl_DoOneEvent + 317
>   12  Tk                                0x0000000104a55932 0x104a47000 + 59698
>   13  Tcl                               0x00000001049695b7 0x10495b000 + 58807
>   14  Tcl                               0x0000000104969e46 Tcl_EvalObjv + 59
>   15  _tkinter.so                       0x00000001037dfe39 Tkapp_Call + 617
>   16  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000a3302 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3730
>   17  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac913 fast_function + 179
>   18  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000a338a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3866
>   19  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac7dc PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2092
>   20  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac988 fast_function + 296
>   21  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000a338a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3866
>   22  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac7dc PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2092
>   23  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac988 fast_function + 296
>   24  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000a338a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3866
>   25  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac7dc PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2092
>   26  libpython2.7.dylib                0x0000000100035c1b function_call + 347
>   27  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010000c761 PyObject_Call + 97
>   28  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000a3cea PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 6266
>   29  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac7dc PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2092
>   30  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac988 fast_function + 296
>   31  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000a338a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3866
>   32  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac7dc PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2092
>   33  libpython2.7.dylib                0x0000000100035c1b function_call + 347
>   34  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010000c761 PyObject_Call + 97
>   35  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010001e7d7 instancemethod_call + 503
>   36  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010000c761 PyObject_Call + 97
>   37  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010006673a slot_tp_init + 106
>   38  libpython2.7.dylib                0x0000000100062465 type_call + 229
>   39  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010000c761 PyObject_Call + 97
>   40  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000a35a5 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 4405
>   41  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac7dc PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2092
>   42  libpython2.7.dylib                0x0000000100035c1b function_call + 347
>   43  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010000c761 PyObject_Call + 97
>   44  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010001e7d7 instancemethod_call + 503
>   45  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010000c761 PyObject_Call + 97
>   46  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010006673a slot_tp_init + 106
>   47  libpython2.7.dylib                0x0000000100062465 type_call + 229
>   48  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010000c761 PyObject_Call + 97
>   49  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000a3cea PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 6266
>   50  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac913 fast_function + 179
>   51  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000a338a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3866
>   52  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac913 fast_function + 179
>   53  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000a338a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3866
>   54  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac7dc PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2092
>   55  libpython2.7.dylib                0x0000000100035c1b function_call + 347
>   56  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010000c761 PyObject_Call + 97
>   57  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010001e7d7 instancemethod_call + 503
>   58  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010000c761 PyObject_Call + 97
>   59  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010006673a slot_tp_init + 106
>   60  libpython2.7.dylib                0x0000000100062465 type_call + 229
>   61  libpython2.7.dylib                0x000000010000c761 PyObject_Call + 97
>   62  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000a35a5 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 4405
>   63  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac913 fast_function + 179
>   64  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000a338a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 3866
>   65  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac7dc PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2092
>   66  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000ac856 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
>   67  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000cb3d4 PyRun_FileExFlags + 164
>   68  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000cc709 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 409
>   69  libpython2.7.dylib                0x00000001000e01ca Py_Main + 2938
>   70  python                            0x0000000100000f14 start + 52
>
> Thread 1:
>   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff8fb354e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
>   1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8fc1d622 _pthread_wqthread + 1023
>   2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8fc1d211 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 2:
>   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff8fb354e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
>   1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8fc1d622 _pthread_wqthread + 1023
>   2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8fc1d211 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 3:
>   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff8fb354e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
>   1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8fc1d7b5 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
>   2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8fc1d211 start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 4:
>   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff8fb34f4e __select + 10
>   1   Tcl                               0x0000000104a08271 0x10495b000 + 709233
>   2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8fc1daab _pthread_body + 180
>   3   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8fc1d9f7 _pthread_start + 286
>   4   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8fc1d221 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 5:: com.apple.NSEventThread
>   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff8fb2d41a mach_msg_trap + 10
>   1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff8fb2c867 mach_msg + 55
>   2   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff8fb21ed1 _kernelrpc_mach_port_set_attributes + 150
>   3   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff8f9e7739 _dispatch_runloop_queue_handle_init + 171
>   4   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff8f9d84b7 _dispatch_runloop_root_queue_create_4CF + 133
>   5   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff7a9091e6 __CFRunLoopFindMode + 502
>   6   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff7a909889 CFRunLoopAddSource + 201
>   7   com.apple.HIToolbox               0x00007fff79ed9897 AdjustCGSSourceInRunLoop(void (*)(__CFRunLoop*, __CFRunLoopSource*, __CFString const*), __CFRunLoop*, __CFRunLoopSource*) + 180
>   8   com.apple.HIToolbox               0x00007fff79ed97bb AddCGSSourceToRunLoop(__CFRunLoop*) + 78
>   9   com.apple.HIToolbox               0x00007fff79eecc52 _BeginEventReceiptOnThread + 181
>   10  com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff7870f4f8 _NSEventThread + 37
>   11  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8fc1daab _pthread_body + 180
>   12  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8fc1d9f7 _pthread_start + 286
>   13  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8fc1d221 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
>     rax: 0x0000000000000307  rbx: 0x00000001003d93f0  rcx: 0x00007fff8f9f9530  rdx: 0x0000000000000307
>     rdi: 0x0000000000000001  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfa160  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfa0f0
>      r8: 0x0000000000000040   r9: 0x00000001003d9408  r10: 0xffffffffffffffff  r11: 0x0000000000012068
>     r12: 0x00000001003d93e0  r13: 0x00000001003d94a0  r14: 0x00007fff986f5a80  r15: 0x0000000102076898
>     rip: 0x00007fff8f9ddd21  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x00007fff9db1224b
>
> Logical CPU:     3
>   Error Code:      0x00000000
>   Trap Number:     6
>
> Binary Images:
>          0x100000000 -        0x100000ff7 +python (???)  /Users/USER/*/python
>          0x100003000 -        0x100146ff7 +libpython2.7.dylib (2.7) <87FF0E63-058F-3190-A882-8E25F3D889C7> /Users/USER/*/libpython2.7.dylib
>          0x1002db000 -        0x1002dcff7 +_locale.so (???)  /Users/USER/*/_locale.so
>          0x1002e0000 -        0x1002e6ff7 +itertools.so (???)  /Users/USER/*/itertools.so
>   <<<<<< LINES OMITTED FOR BREVITY >>>>>>
>       0x7fff8fc2b000 -     0x7fff8fc32fff  libsystem_symptoms.dylib (532.1.1) <8FB7CA37-79EF-3651-B5B9-B5E1E0947067> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
>       0x7fff8fc33000 -     0x7fff8fc53ff7  libsystem_trace.dylib (518.20.8)  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
>       0x7fff8fc54000 -     0x7fff8fc59ffb  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <9F7C2AD8-A9A7-3DE4-828D-B0F0F166AAA0> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
>       0x7fff8fc5a000 -     0x7fff8fc83ff7  libxpc.dylib (972.20.3) <85EB25FD-218F-38EE-9E69-391CC8EBE6C5> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
>
> External Modification Summary:
>     Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
>       task_for_pid: 0
>       thread_create: 0
>       thread_set_state: 0
>     Calls made by this process:
>       task_for_pid: 0
>       thread_create: 0
>       thread_set_state: 0
>     Calls made by all processes on this machine:
>       task_for_pid: 542465
>       thread_create: 0
>       thread_set_state: 0
>
> VM Region Summary:
>   ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=254.5M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=254.5M(100%)
>   Writable regions: Total=96.5M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=96.5M(100%)
>
> ```
>                             VIRTUAL   REGION
> ```
>
> REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
>   ===========                     =======  ======= 
>   Activity Tracing                   256K        2 
>   CoreUI image file                  144K        3 
>   Dispatch continuations            8192K        2 
>   Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
>   MALLOC                            61.8M       54 
>   MALLOC guard page                   32K        7 
>   Memory Tag 242                      12K        2 
>   STACK GUARD                       56.0M        7 
>   Stack                             10.1M        7 
>   VM_ALLOCATE                         48K        7 
>   __DATA                            21.0M      292 
>   __IMAGE                            528K        2 
>   __LINKEDIT                       115.0M       66 
>   __TEXT                           139.5M      288 
>   __UNICODE                          556K        2 
>   mapped file                       43.2M        9 
>   shared memory                     16.3M       12 
>   ===========                     =======  ======= 
>   TOTAL                            472.4M      747
>
> Model: MacBookPro11,1, BootROM MBP111.0138.B17, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2,4 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.16f68
>   Graphics: Intel Iris, Intel Iris, Built-In
>   Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343531533641465238412D50422020
>   Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343531533641465238412D50422020
>   AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x112), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.47.1a8)
>   Bluetooth: Version 5.0.1f7, 3 services, 17 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
>   Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en0
>   Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256F, 251 GB
>   USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
>   USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
>   USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
>   USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
>   Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.2

Comment: My guess is that you are running into issues with interactions between multiprocess and GUI code.  Which mpl backend are you using? If the goal is to save files I suggest using one of the non-interactive backends.  See http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

Comment: the default backend. However, if I use
'import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('MacOSX')'
Then I see no plot.
Everything was properly working before updating to OSX Sierra, and now I've been fighting with this issue for a week...

Comment: Some updates below.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the "start method" to "spawn" instead of the default of "fork". See https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods for further details.

This worked for me on a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, more info: If I run a first process from terminal, whose script 'visl.py' is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, './lib')
import visualizer

visualizer.Visualizer()
```

and then a second process from a different terminal instance, whose script 'logr.py' is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, './lib')
import logger


args_logger = {'sampling_time_ms': 5, 'plotting_time_ms': 100}
logger.Logger(args_logger)
```

It works. Then: how to run two python processes from a single script?

Comment: BTW: I solved the issue with a work-around. Apparently there are some issues with the multi process management in Python. Now Ruby is used to launch and handle two different processes. It's quite an horrible solution I know, but is the better idea I came up with (I'm a hobbyist, not a professional programmer).
The solution has been posted in the GitHub repo.